# Can't insert the big Enter key back into my keyboard

Tags: keyboard

After I missed some beer onto my keyboard, several keys aren't working well now. I justed wanted to clean the Enter key, but now neither me nor my cat can't put it back.  God (or Bill Gates whichever) I have another key in the right bottom corner to be able to ask this question here, so... is there any special technique to fix it? I already tried to use little scissors, but still got no result.

[image]

Comment: Just do what [this guy did](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jpACbI-lS6U&feature=player_detailpage#t=14s) it'll eventually go in.

Comment: Doesn't everyone else have about 10 old keyboards lying around?  I know that I do...every computer I get, I get a new keyboard and they just pile up.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Its a bit of a pain in the rear but you need to VERY CAREFULLY hook the stabilisers/wire guides into the little 'hinge' like things, then push it back in. You'd want to use a pair of tweezers or a toothpick for that. The trick is to let the guides hang off the key vertically down and just over the keyboard and very carefully push it in place.

Do not use force. Make sure everything aligns before putting it in. As long as the wire is hooked in place, everything will work smoothly ... unless the wire goes out of place. Also the little plastic hinges sometimes break, which makes it even more of a pain.

EDIT : I've added a SE approved red free hand circle version of your image that shows which guide is to be hooked in where

[image]

Comment: ***VERY CAREFULLY*** meaning it's quite easy to snap the little bits of plastic.

Comment: And it is PAINFULLY fiddly. Its a little like rocket surgery on a mouse

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem. After trying any possible way to put my ENTER key back on keyboard with those little metal wires, i just took them out and put the key back into place without wires. Now it works perfectly.

Comment: you dont even need those wires :)